# Regarding extending of classes

Tags: java

I have a query in java, that since `Object` class is the parent class for all, I want to know that is `Object` class is being implicitly extended by every class in java.

For example: if I make an object class `B` then I extend class `A` that is ok since in java, class can extend only a single class at most, but since my class `B` has implicitly extended the `Object` class then how can it extend class `A`? Please advise.

Comment: `B` extends `A` extends `Object`

Comment: `Object` will always be the lowest part in your class-hierarchy.

Comment: Please consider the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how to ask questions here. When you extend a class in Java you implicitly extend the Object-class, too, as this is part of your base class. If you don't extend any class, but create a new one, you implicitly extend Object.

Comment: class B extends A {} which implicitly extends Object

Answer (score 0):

Only when a parent is not specified does it implicitly inherit off of `Object`, otherwise it only inherits off of the specified parent.

**Side note:**

This is allowed:

```
  C
  |
  A
  |
  B
```

In the above case, replace `C` with `Object` to be in line with what you're asking.

This is not allowed:

```
C   A
 \ /
  B
```

The inheritance can be as deep as you want it to be, but one object cannot have multiple parents.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a family tree where individuals only have one parent. Each individual only has one parent, but all that parent's ancestors are also ancestors of the individual. That's what's meant when it is said that all classes extend `Object`: it is the most remote ancestor of all, though only the direct ancestor (parent) of those classes that are declared with `extends Object` or with no `extends` declaration at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you know the concept but you must be a bit confused. Think of a tree. Object class is the root of that tree. It has leaves and other nodes in between. No matter how your class hierarchy is designed, it will eventually an `Object` because its root is that. So you can extend any class (not abstract or Interface), without thinking of `Object` class. Because `Object` extention will be done automatically for you.

Answer (score -1):

Here, I will suggest, the keyword is **EXPLICIT**. You can **EXPLICITLY** extend only one class. But if you don't do that Java will implicitly extend your class with Object class. If you have done that Object must be somewhere up in the hierarchy of the inherited class.

Comment: You're kind of repeating what's been said in the other **4** answers.